# Forward authenticated user to user.page on /login uri

Tags: 8, users, routes, event-subscribers

If an authenticated user navigates to /login on a Drupal 8 site, she gets the "access denied" error. I want the site to redirect that user to /user (route user.page) instead.
Unfortunately my RouteSubscriber doesn't work:

```
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {

    /* @var \Symfony\Component\Routing\Route $route */
    if ($route = $collection->get('user.login')) {
      $route->setPath('/anmelden');
      $route->setRequirements([]);
      $route->setDefaults(array(
         '_controller' => '\Drupal\asdentbase\Controller\LogonController::login',
         '_title' => 'Anmelden'
       ));
    }
```

And my LogonController looks like

```
public function login() {

    if ($this->currentUser()->isAuthenticated()) {
      return $this->redirect('user.page');
    }

    $rc =
    ...
```

The route redirection to /anmelden works fine. But my LogonController::login function is never called for already authenticated users. There's seems to be any further magic in the core.

**More detail:**

I also have a route in mymodule.routing.yml like

```
asdentbase.login:
  path: '/anmelden'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\asdentbase\Controller\LogonController::login'
    _title: 'Anmelden'
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to register your class in the event subscriber serivce. Create a YML similar to this:

`asdentbase.services.yml`

```
services:
  asdentbase.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\asdentbase\RouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Comment: I already did this. That's why the redirection basically works.